# Setting Default value of input textbox in Jquery EasyUI dialog

Tags: javascript, input, dialog, jquery-easyui

I have googled and looked throughout the whole documentation and could not figure out why value of input text is not shown. I am using FireFox latest version and below is what I have done so far.

```
 <input name="amount" class="easyui-validatebox" id="d_amount" value="">
```

In regular html or php page we can give `value="300"` to set default value, but in EasyUI, it is not possible. So I was thinking possible alternative like below:

```
  <script>
   var m = '300';
   document.getElementById("d_amount").value.innerHTML=m;
  </script>
```

Nothing is shown and I am not getting any error. Any EasyUI expert, please help me.

**NOTE:** this input field is inside the dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?topic=6281.0). The trick is to use the code inside `$(function(){});`

```
$(function(){
    var m=300;
    $('#d_amount').textbox('setValue', m);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

To set the default value, you have to set the value attribute. However, that does not necessarily update the value property so you need to do both. So given:

```
<input name="amount" class="easyui-validatebox" id="d_amount" value="">
```

set the default value by setting the value attribute:

```
var input = document.getElementById('d_amount')
input.setAttribute('value', 'whatever');
```

now set the value property:

```
input.value = 'whatever';
```

Note that you can also get a reference to the input as a member of the form that it's in:

```
var input = document.formName.d_amount;
```

Comment: thanks for your input. Easyui may not allow to set value attribute in this way as this does not solve as well.

Comment: Not so easy then? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code

```
$("#d_amount").numberbox({
    min:0,
    precision:2,
    value:300

})
```

Reference : [numberbox](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/numberbox.php)

Or try this one

```
$("#d_amount").textbox({
    buttonText:'Search',
    iconCls:'icon-man',
    iconAlign:'left',
    value:"300"
});
```

Reference : [textbox](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/textbox.php)

Comment: still not working. The solution is likely to be in Easyui code. At first, I am trying something like `$('#d_amount').validatebox('setValue', m);` but could not make it work.

Comment: Thanks Ridwan. But my question is textbox, and not numberbox. I have tried your code and unfortunately it is not working either. Have you tried the code yourself in easyui form?

Comment: 0.00 is the output I got.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to set the value inside `$(document).ready(function(){}`

```
  ....
  $("#d_amount").numberbox('setValue','300');
  ....
```

if still not working, just try to set `name` and `id` as the same name and id

```
<input name="d_amount" class="easyui-validatebox" id="d_amount" value="">
```

I am always working with this numberbox and it's working

Comment: I am using the input field inside dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I have found your thread because I am also having the same issue and I have just across this thing today. Your case is a little bit different (maybe) then my case because you want to set the default which can be changed by the user later (I believe). In my case, the value will be fixed (will not be changed) so I have applied a trick and hopefully it can give some ideas to you and others who are having same issue. Please refer below:

In first page says pageA.php:

```
<select name="myThing" id="myThing">
    <option value="Your Desired Value" selected="selected">Something</option>
</select>
```

Still in the same page, under your `$(document).ready( function(){` put the code below:

```
$("#myThing").val($("#myThing option:first").val());
```

That code is to make sure your desired value appears at the first row in the drop down. I say this because in EasyUI it seems when I use drop down and put single option, the first row will be blank and the second row will hold your input. So that is the trick to ensure your desired value appears on top and selected. Put the `select` under the `form` then during normal post, you will be able to get the value of it in the posted page. Enjoy. Thank you.

Suggestion: if your value can be changed by user, use `placeholder` and you can hide the default value from user using my trick.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 document.getElementById("d_amount").value=m;
```

you don't need innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem and it was solved using the following

First my input was in the form like this:

```
<input name="hostFirstName" id="hostFirstName"  class="easyui-textbox">
```

I needed to load content from the db then pre-fill the input with this data so the user could edit the content.
I used the following javascript.

**NOTE:** i didn't hide this away inside an anonymous function() and it is working. I tested this first from the F12 console to make sure it was working before changing my code.

```
//populate with existing data
$('#hostFirstName').textbox('setValue', "Is this working?");
```

The docs on jeasyui.com don't provide this example when you look at the textbox api reference. But they do provide an example when looking at the combobox (http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php#) the combobox and textbox use the same setValue method.

Hopefully this works for you like it does for me.